# deduping - case sensitive?

Tags: civievent, duplicate-contacts

In many case, when visitors register to a public event, they use either capital case for or small case for their last name. Therefore, the deduplication engine considers both to be different. Can it be circumvent?

Comment: I think this is a really good point and that Deduping should be made to be case insensitive - unless someone comes up with some suggestions this may be something that requires financial or development resources to get progressed via the JIRA system

Answer (score 1):

On workaround/better solution is to change the format of the value entered by end users so DAMIEN is converted into Damien, and the dedupe rule compares Damien=Damien and all works smoothly.

https://github.com/TechToThePeople/civicrm-normalise

X+